# Can't add pkpass to ipad, safari can't download

Tags: passkit

I've created a pkpass using jpasskit, but can't add that to ipad. It's showing that safari can't download the file.

These are working perfectly fine in iPhone devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad doesn't support .pkpass files because Wallet is not available on the iPad.  You should adjust your user experience to display a notification to revisit the link on an iPhone or on Safari on a Mac.